# How can I make the data be found from dataset?

Tags: r

Below are my codes:

```
library(car)
dat <- filter(Prestige, complete.cases(Prestige))
m1 <- lm(prestige ~ type, data = dat)
```

The results says "object 'prestige' not found", but the data of Prestige does include "prestige". What is wrong?

Comment: You are using `filter` from package `stats`, not `dplyr::filter`. It's a packages conflict. Use the second form in this comment.

Comment: Use `library(dplyr)` up top to get the correct `filter()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and found a way around it using a logical row identification:

```
library(car)
dat <- Prestige[complete.cases(Prestige),]
m1 <- lm(prestige ~ type, data = dat)
```

`complete.cases` returns the rows that are complete as a binary True or False. These logical values correspond to row numbers, when placed inside the `[` you can achieve your desired result.

As mentioned by Rui Barradas:

```
library(car)
dat <- dplyr::filter(Prestige, complete.cases(Prestige))
m1 <- lm(prestige ~ type, data = dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `filter` function from the `stats` package but I think you meant to use the one from the `dplyr` package. Try loading the dplyr package:

```
library("car")
library("dplyr")

dat <- Prestige
dat <- filter(Prestige, complete.cases(Prestige))
m1 <- lm(prestige ~ type, data = dat)
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
dplyr::filter(Prestige, complete.cases(Prestige))
```